# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() using mpdf in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I m getting warning in my model file in codeigniter saying **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** when i am trying to edit my where condition.

Actually i want to load records according to **foreign key**.

When i am adding this line of code,  `$this->db->where('project.id',$id);` in model, i am getting the above error.

**Controller File**

```
<?php

class Createpdf extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->library('m_pdf');
 $this->load->model('boq_pdf_model');
 $this->load->model('project_list_model');
}
function pdf()
{
 $id= $this->uri->segment(3) ; 
 $data['projects'] = $this->project_list_model->show_projects();
$data['boq'] = $this->boq_pdf_model->get_boq($id);
 $this->load->view('boq/boq_report',$data);

}
public function topdf(){
//this data will be passed on to the view
$data['the_content']='RCJ Constructions';

//load the view, pass the variable and do not show it but "save" the output into $html variable
$html=$this->load->view('boq/boq_report', $data, true); 

//this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
$pdfFilePath = "boq_report.pdf";

//load mPDF library
//$this->load->library('m_pdf');
//actually, you can pass mPDF parameter on this load() function
$pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();


$id= $this->uri->segment(3) ; 
$data['projects'] = $this->project_list_model->show_projects();
$data['boq'] = $this->boq_pdf_model->get_boq($id);
$html = $this->load->view('boq/boq_report', $data, true);

//generate the PDF!
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);


//offer it to user via browser download! (The PDF won't be saved on your server HDD)
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
    }
}
?>
```

**Model File**

```
function get_boq($id){ 
    $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('boq');
        $this->db->join('project', 'project.id = boq.project_id'); 
        $this->db->where('project.id',$id);
        $this->db->order_by('item_no','ASC');
        $getData = $this->db->get();
        if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
        return $getData->result_array();
        else return null; 

    }
}
```

**View File**

```
 <?php
     foreach ($boq as $rows) {
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $rows['unit'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['rate']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['laboure_hrs'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['laboure_cost'] ?></td>
       </tr>
   <?php
       //$i++;
       }
   ?>
```

boq table

id | rate| unit| project_id

project table

id | location| client_id

> For your information, i am using MPDF library as well and i am loading it in my controller.

Any help wil be highly appreciated ?

Thanks

Comment: You have used $id= $this->uri->segment(3) can you please let us know the URL structure and also have you checked whether you are getting an $id value?

Comment: site_url('createpdf/pdf/'.$row->id)

Comment: And what about the second are you getting the value of $id. Debug it. As Rajkumar R "If model returns null means it will show the error invalid argument". So check it whether it is passing the value of not

Comment: @ashik add your both table(project,boq) structure

Comment: boq table

id | rate| unit| project_id

project table

id | location| client_id

Comment: it works when i add project_id  manually into url as below.http://localhost/rcj-constructions/back-end/index.php/createpdf/pdf/1 .

Comment: Hello as per your comments mention that it works when you add an id manually. It means that the value for `site_url('createpdf/pdf/'.$row->id)` is not proper you must check it value I mean exact output of the url. Along with that please check the $id value which is passed in `function get_boq($id)`. May be it is due to improper value of null value is been passed. Please revert

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the values present or not. If model returns null means it will show the error invalid argument. So, do like this:-

```
<?php
if(count($boq) > 0) { 
    foreach ($boq as $rows) {
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $rows['unit'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $rows['rate']?></td>
           <td><?php echo $rows['laboure_hrs'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $rows['laboure_cost'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
       //$i++;
    }
} else {
    echo "No Results Found";
}
?>
```

Comment: values are loading when before i add '$this->db->where('project.id',$id);' code in model.

Comment: affter add your code it shows No Results Found.please help me

Comment: Change this and check $this->db->join('project', 'boq.id = project.project_id');

Comment: Add your both table structure in your question

Answer (score 0):

Please check you query using `echo $this->db->last_query();` after getting query paste in your database check it get record or not. you can change `$this->db->join('project', 'project.id = boq.project_id'); to $this->db->join('project', 'project.id = boq.project_id','left');`

i think you use join then project table have not any data that's may issue.

Comment: no there are records. can u tell me the way to pass project_id with url